# S3 File Post-Processing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a protocol setup which sends recorded audio to an S3 bucket as a .webm file.

I would like each of these files to be immediately processed when they hit the bucket. How can I do this?

There are two steps to the post-processing, 1) convert the file from .webm to .wav, 2) run a [program](https://vamp-plugins.org/sonic-annotator/) which analyses the audio.

On my computer, in Terminal, I would do this:

Step 1)

```
FILE="file.webm";
ffmpeg -i "${FILE}" -vn -ab 128k -ar 44100 -y "${FILE%.webm}.wav";
```

then Step 2)

```
./sonic-annotator -f -d vamp:pyin:pyin:notes -w csv file.wav
```

How can I do this via my Amazon S3 bucket, all in the cloud?

Comment: Read [Processing user-generated content using AWS Lambda and FFmpeg](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/media/processing-user-generated-content-using-aws-lambda-and-ffmpeg/).

Answer (score 0):

You can create an **AWS Lambda for this job.**
You need to create a trigger for that bucket which will invoke that AWS Lambda as soon as a file is added to the bucket, the triggered lambda will run the code.
Check out this link for the [trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html).
Check out this link for the [AWS Lambda creation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/getting-started-create-function.html).

Answer (score 0):

**"I would like each of these files to be immediately processed when they hit the bucket"**

If you want a Lambda function to run when you add an object to an Amazon S3 bucket, you can setup a Lambda function in response to a new object being placed into the bucket. For details, see [Using AWS Lambda with Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html).

For the other tasks, you can look at using other AWS Services. For example, to analyze a video, you can use the Amazon Rekognition service. Using this service, you can obtain a lot of details about a video.